# Podio $client_id and $client_secret are declared static inside class Podio ,so they should keep their values, but they don't

Tags: php, static-variables, podio

Here is my code

```
class User extends CI_Controller {

    /**
     * __construct function.
     * 
     * @access public
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct() {

        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library(array('session'));
        $this->load->helper(array('url'));
        $this->load->model('user_model');

    }


    public function dashboard()
    {       
        if (!isset($_SESSION['logged_in']) || $_SESSION['logged_in'] != true) {//not logged         
            redirect(base_url().'user/login');
        }else
        {

            $data=(array)$this->user_model->get_user($_SESSION['user_id']);

            //$data=(array)$this->user_model->get_user(3);
            $data['title'] ='Dashboard Page';
                //'heading' => 'My Heading',
                //'message' => 'My Message'

            Podio::setup(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET);

            $orgs=PodioOrganization::get_all(  );

                $this->load->view('header',$data);
                $this->load->view('user/page_header',$data);
                $this->load->view('user/dashboard',$data);
                $this->load->view('user/footer');



        }


    }       

    public function test_auth()
    {
        // Set up the REDIRECT_URI -- which is just the URL for this file.

        if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in']) && $_SESSION['logged_in'] === true ) {
            redirect(base_url().'user/dashboard');
        }
        else{

            Podio::setup(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET);

            if (!isset($_GET['code']) && !Podio::is_authenticated()) {

              // User is not being reidrected and does not have an active session
              // We just display a link to the authentication page on podio.com
              $auth_url = htmlentities(Podio::authorize_url(REDIRECT_URI));
              //print "<a href='{$auth_url}'>Start authenticating</a>";
              redirect($auth_url); 

            } elseif (Podio::is_authenticated()) {

              // User already has an active session. You can make API calls here:
              print "You were already authenticated and no authentication is needed.";

            }
            elseif (isset($_GET['code'])) {

              // User is being redirected back from podio.com after authenticating.
              // The authorization code is available in $_GET['code']
              // We use it to finalize the authentication

              // If there was a problem $_GET['error'] is set:
              if (isset($_GET['error'])) {
                print "There was a problem. The server said: {$_GET['error_description']}";
              }
              else {
                // Finalize authentication. Note that we must pass the REDIRECT_URI again.
                Podio::authenticate_with_authorization_code($_GET['code'], REDIRECT_URI);


                    $_SESSION['user_id']      = 1;
                    $_SESSION['logged_in']    = (bool)true;
                    $_SESSION['access_token'] = (string)Podio::$oauth->access_token ;
                    $_SESSION['refresh_token']= (string)Podio::$oauth->refresh_token  ;

                    redirect(base_url().'user/dashboard');


              }

            }
        }   
    }
```

Function `test_auth()` is called prior to function `dashboard()`.

In `test_auth()` I call `Podio::setup(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET);` so the `$client_id` and `$client_secret`  are set.

In Podio class the `$client_id` and `$client_secret` are declared static ,so they should keep their values, also in the `dashboard()` function, but they don't.
If I don't reset them in `dashboard()` function,by calling `Podio::setup(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET);` again, I have an error telling me I have to set values to `$client_id` and `$client_secret`.
Why is this happening?

Comment: Where are `CLIENT_ID` and `CLIENT_SECRET` defined? It seems they are not defined.

Comment: they are defined in another file, I don't have  errors from that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid Podio reauthentification each and every time I query data from Podio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45204272/how-to-avoid-podio-reauthentification-each-and-every-time-i-query-data-from-podi)

Comment: it's the same code but it's a different quetion (I have put this question at the end of How to avoid Podio reauthentification each and every time I query data from Podio? , who knows, maybe someone will answer)